How to Generate and Revoke Kubernetes Admin Config Files in a Kubeadm Cluster?
I have a Kubernetes cluster set up using kubeadm, and currently, developers can access and deploy using the default admin config file. However, I need to generate a new admin config file and revoke access from the existing one to ensure that the old config file can no longer be used for deployments.
Here's what I tried so far:
kubeadm init phase kubeconfig admin --apiserver-advertise-address $IP --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/pki
Questions:
What are the best practices for generating a new admin config file in a Kubernetes cluster managed by kubeadm?
How can I effectively revoke the old admin config file so that it cannot be used for deployments or any other administrative tasks?
Are there any recommended tools or commands for managing and rotating Kubernetes admin config files securely?
Any ideas, suggestions, or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
